# Chrome Browser - Absolute positioning and floating issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-float

Here's an issue that's been bugging me all day. I'm not exactly sure how to describe it other than I'm having an issue with a `div` floating over a floated container and it seems to be only an issue in Chrome.

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/H8vVf/ . There should be a stripe next to text but in Chrome, it looks like a strike-through.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">SOME GOOD TEXT</div>
    <div class="stripe"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper::after {
     content: " ";
     display: block;
}
.content {
     float: left;
}
.stripe {
     background-color: black;
     width: 100%;
     display: inline;
     position: absolute;
     height: 1em;
}​
```

I've figured out a workaround for it but I was just wondering if anyone can explain to me what is going wrong here and why. If not, I'll just go on my merry way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> *I'm having an issue with a `div` floating over a floated container...*

Normally, when you [`float:`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats) something, the other content on the page should flow *around* it.

**Quote OP:**

> *There should be a stripe next to text but in Chrome, it looks like a
>   strike-through.*

I'm not sure what you mean by "strike-through", but you've defined the element with class `.stripe` to be 100% wide which means it will be 100% the width of its parent.  In this case, the parent of `.stripe` is the element with class `.wrapper`.  Since the `.wrapper` class has no defined width, by default, it will be 100% as wide as its parent which is the window.  Therefore, as you've defined it, the stripe will be 100% as wide as the window.

**Quote OP:**

> *I was just wondering if anyone can explain to me what is going wrong here and why.*

Regarding your code...

```
.stripe {
     background-color: black;
     width: 100%;
     display: inline;
     position: absolute;
     height: 1em;
}​
```

[`display: inline`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-formatting) is a property for elements within the content flow.

However, [`position: absolute`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#absolute-positioning) takes the element out of the content flow.

It makes no sense this way.  In other words, it can't both be *in the flow* and *out of the flow* at the same time.

[Here is the W3C spec which explains the CSS2 Visual Formatting Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html) as well as a [detailed comparison of normal flow, floats and absolute positioning](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#comparison).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation (and for the edit, since I was quite tired and the question was sloppily construed). I will have to keep those links in mind in the future. Also, I'll need to rethink my workaround.

Comment: @Relic, the OP was asking for an explanation, not a solution.  I gave him a detailed explanation, you did not.  So because you _think_ I down-voted yours, you then down-vote mine.  Classy behavior.  Some of the best answers on SO are fully written out... they are not just a jsFiddle link with one-sentence containing the words, _"has something to do with..."_.  In fact, his issue had nothing to do with what you claimed as I clearly explain above.